# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0,,ERROR (SearchSMFController.java:120) Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java

can anyone solve this, I'M GETTING

```
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2014-05-23 10:33:18,635 [http-8080-1] ERROR (SearchSMFController.java:120) Index: 0, Size: 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(Unknown Source)``
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.swap(Unknown Source)
    at com.hbc.vp.services.SMFService.getUpdatedBannersList(SMFService.java:609)
    at com.hbc.vp.services.SMFService.getBannerList(SMFService.java:582)
    at com.hbc.vp.controllers.SearchSMFController.setUpForm(SearchSMFController.java:113)



at line java:120 ==LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);

at line==Collections.swap(saksBannersList, 0, 1);

at line==return getUpdatedBannersList(bannersListModified);

at line==smfForm.setBannersLst(smfService.getBannerList());
```

Comment: seems that `saksBannersList` is empty.Please post the code where you are manipulating `saksBannersList`

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your logic of accessing the list. Your list might be empty, then you are forcing to get something from the list. i.e (list.get(0))

Check this part of your code.

```
 at com.hbc.vp.services.SMFService.getUpdatedBannersList(SMFService.java:609)
```